# How do i get the lowest sum of input numbers?

Tags: c#

I've got a task for printing the highest sum of numbers, lowest sum of numbers and the average of numbers which were printed. i managed to get the higest sum of numbers but with the lowest somehow didn't work for me at all.

for example:
7 3 -2 6 -10 8 -5 3 -2 1

their Interim amount:
7 10 8 14 4 12 7 10 8 9

the output will be:

Higest Interim amount: 14

Lowest Interim amount: 4

Avg of numbers: 0.9

my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0, i, sum = 0, c = 0, max, min;
            max = min = num;
            for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                sum = sum + num;
                if (sum >= max)
                    max = sum;
                else if (sum <= min)
                    min = sum;
                c++;
                Console.WriteLine("sum:{0}", sum);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("count={0} avg={1}", c, sum / (float)c);
            Console.WriteLine("Max:{0} Min:{1}", max, min);
        }
```

Comment: Just use pencil & paper and walk thru your code by hand.  Write down each variable and track the values. You don't have to go thru all the input, after one or two numbers you will see the problem.

Comment: If I take a sequence of numbers, the sum will always be the same no matter how I sum them. Can you define what *highest* and *lowest* mean here. And, ... this code is never a good sign `num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. Throwing an exception if a user fat-fingers a numeric entry isn't the way to go. Consider using `int.TryParse` instead

Comment: Don't use an else, use two ifs

Comment: Don't need to use `c` or `c++` (hah) - it'll always be 10. Parameterize the 10

Answer (score 1):

You make both min and max start at 0, so the min will only update if you get a negative value for the cumulative sum (which does not happen in your example). (Would be the same for the max value if all your sums remained negative).

You need to start with the numeric equivalent of min = +Infinity and max = -Infinity.

i.e.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0, i, sum = 0, c = 0;
            int max = int.MinValue;
            int min = int.MaxValue;
```

(Thanks @Caius Jard for the syntax, I know nothing about C#)

Comment: Acceptable numeric equivalent of +/-infinity here being int.MaxValue/MinValue respectively

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the initial `min` to 0, and then only set the minimum to the sum if it drops below that. If you set initial minimum and maximum to the first number input you won't have this problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0, i, sum = 0, c = 0, max, min;
            for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if(i == 0)
                {
                     min = num;
                     max = num;
                }
                sum = sum + num;
                if (sum >= max)
                    max = sum;
                else if (sum <= min)
                    min = sum;
                c++;
                Console.WriteLine("sum:{0}", sum);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("count={0} avg={1}", c, sum / (float)c);
            Console.WriteLine("Max:{0} Min:{1}", max, min);
        }
```